# TableRow mouse hover highlight flicker issue JavaFX 11+

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-11

I've been using a piece of CSS successful until I migrated to OpenJDK 11/OpenJFX 13 (also a problem with OpenJFX11). Basically it highlights the row the mouse is hovering over:

```
   .table-view.customtable .table-row-cell:hover .table-cell {
     -fx-background-color: red;
 }
```

I've changed all the colours in this sample to make the effect more obvious.
Under Java 8 only the row the mouse is hovering over highlights and even when there is continuous data being updated to the table there are no nasty side effects/flickers.
Under OpenJFX 11-13 Unless the user is hovering over the middle row in the table the highlight can be seen reflected as a flicker on the opposite row from the center, so if the hovered row is 3 above the center then the row 3 below the center will flicker the same colour. This is obviously not a good look :(
It only happens when the mouse is hovering and the table is continuously updating. Please feel free to try this sample under Java 8 as well to see that it doesn't flicker. If it's a genuine bug I'll report it but hopefully there is a different way of achieving the same without the flicker in JFX 13?
The class below shows a much more simplified version of how the TableView in the real application is updated from the Server but it achieves the same issue with the flickering.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private TableView<TableData> table = new TableView<>();
    private ObservableList<TableData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(600);

        TableColumn<TableData, TableData> oneColumn = new TableColumn<>("One");
        oneColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        TableColumn<TableData, String> twoColumn = new TableColumn<>("Two");
        twoColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        TableColumn<TableData, String> threeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Three");
        threeColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        TableColumn<TableData, String> fourColumn = new TableColumn<>("Four");
        fourColumn.setMinWidth(100);

        table.setEditable(false);
        table.setPrefWidth(1100);
        table.setMaxWidth(1100);
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(oneColumn, twoColumn, threeColumn, fourColumn);
        table.setFixedCellSize(25.0);
        table.getStyleClass().add("customtable");
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        oneColumn.setCellValueFactory((param) -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue()));
        oneColumn.setCellFactory((param) -> new NameCell());
        twoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("twoColumn"));
        twoColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getTwoColumn()));
        threeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("threeColumn"));
        threeColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getThreeColumn()));
        fourColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fourColumn"));
        fourColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue().getFourColumn()));

        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        HBox hBox = new HBox(table);
        HBox.setHgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(hBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        //generate some random table data
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                    updateTableData();
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
        // PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(new Duration(100));
        // pauseTransition.setOnFinished(f -> updateTableData(););
        // pauseTransition.play();

    }


    private void updateTableData() {
        List<TableData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            int rand = random.nextInt(20);
            list.add(new TableData("Manufacturer" + i, "User " + i, "value" + rand, "desc" + rand));
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            data.setAll(list);
        });
    }


    class NameCell extends TableCell<TableData, TableData> {

        public NameCell() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(TableData item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (!empty && item != null) {
                if (item.getOneColumn() != null) {
                    setText(item.getOneColumn());
                }
            } else {
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    }


    class TableData implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String oneColumn;
        private String twoColumn;
        private String threeColumn;
        private String fourColumn;


        public TableData(String oneColumn, String twoColumn, String threeColumn, String fourColumn) {
            this.oneColumn = oneColumn;
            this.twoColumn = twoColumn;
            this.threeColumn = threeColumn;
            this.fourColumn = fourColumn;
        }


        public String getOneColumn() {
            return oneColumn;
        }

        public String getTwoColumn() {
            return twoColumn;
        }

        public String getThreeColumn() {
            return threeColumn;
        }

        public String getFourColumn() {
            return fourColumn;
        }

    }

}
```

and the css file to go with this:

```
    .customtable{
    -fx-background-color:darkgray;
 }

 .customtable .column-header{
     -fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
     -fx-padding: -0.0625em -0.0625em -0.0625em -0.0625em;
 }

 .customtable .table-cell {
    -fx-background-color:darkgray;
     -fx-border-color: transparent -fx-table-cell-border-color -fx-table-cell-border-color transparent;
     -fx-padding: 0.0em;
     -fx-alignment: CENTER-LEFT;
 }

 .customtable .table-cell:odd {
    -fx-background-color:derive(darkgray,20.0%);
  }

 .table-view.customtable .table-row-cell:hover .table-cell {
     -fx-background-color: red;
 }
```

Thanks for any help

Update: Adding the following hack prevents the mirror image ghosting when highlighting a row but it doesn't stop the selected row flickering as the table updates, it possibly even causes it owing to the refresh.

```
 table.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TableData>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TableData> c) {
            table.refresh();
        }
    });
```

I have the listener on getItems() anyway which I use to update intial column widths to content and to highlight  the selected row.

Anyone have any ideas of a workaround for the flickering selected row?

Comment: looks like a bug in cell reuse (not sure if/what changed) - a dirty hack around seems a call `table.refresh()` (can't believe that I wrote that ;) Please consider reporting a bug, maybe somebody is willing to take a deeper look

Comment: Where are you suggesting the table.refresh() should go, on the mouseMoved event attach to the table? I'll definitely report the bug.

Comment: Does anyone have any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: what's wrong with refresh? (except being an abomination ;) simply do it after setting the data ..

Comment: It does stop the mirrored highlight flashing effect. The actual highlighted row is still flickering when the table updates but I can live with that for now. It's a bit of nasty hack but needs must! Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm seeing some issues the hack of adding a refresh call to everytime the ObservableList is updated. There quite a large spike in CPU usage under high data ingress with this hack in. Is there any other solution for this issue?